# Excluding jars lib directory of tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jar

I have a project with spring in which I have the jar ojdbc6 version 11.2.0.3. I have to deploy it on a server with a tomcat in the folder that has the ojdbc14 lib, and orai18n.jar ojdb6 files. When I try to deploy I have the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;`

I have done tests with a local tomcat and the problem is to be the orai18n.jar file in the lib folder of tomcat Is there a way to ignore this jar to make the deployment? I can not remove it because the server if there are projects that use this jar.

Comment: This is why all webapps should be completely self-contained. It's those other webapps relying on having the driver in tomcat's lib directory that need to be fixed :-/

Answer (score 0):

If those libraries are provided by your Tomcat container, then you shouldn't include them in your WAR file. Simply declare them with `<scope>provided</scope>` in your pom.